# Hosting vendor consultant sends proposal to my manager without any background information

Tags: professionalism, communication, manager

So unbeknownst to my manager, I've been pricing out different managed server companies to allow us to upgrade to a service with more flexibility and features. This is going to be significantly more than our current setup hence me doing my due diligence. My plan was to get all the options and present the case of upgrading as well as ease in the price increase in a presentation.

One of the vendors went though our website and found my manager's email and emailed him a proposal as well. Now my manager is asking questions and has caused me to jump the gun on stating my case for an upgrade in an informal manner.

I feel like this is poor form, but I wanted to verify to see if some vendors do this. I've never had a vendor do this before.

Comment: Why were you working on something with your manager not knowing about it at all?  Is that normal in your workplace?

Comment: Poor form for me is not keeping your manager in the loop on your intentions. Even if this was to be spent on your own time, there may be a lot of information here that you lack that can be provided, and your manager should never be surprised by your activities. Even if you're "empowered" to look outside in this manner, a quick note saying "I've got some ideas for a new hosting proposal. I'll let you know when I've got something to show you." is always a good idea.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere: I have vendors do this all the time. Perhaps it's a new sales tactic. Vendors frequently attempt to end around my directs and come straight at me for proposals.

Comment: `I feel like this is poor form` - Yes, on your part. `One of the vendors went though our website and found my manager's email and emailed him a proposal as well`. - Yes. That's what sales people do. They try to sell stuff.

Answer (score 5):

**Of course vendors do this**

A vendor is not going to assume that you are generating a secret proposal, but that you are an underling being dispatched to gather information on behalf of your manager, who is either the decision-maker or at least closer to the decision-makers than you are. They want to win the business, so they look you up on LinkedIn/your website and attempt to go directly to whoever they identify as the decision-maker with the hope of influencing the outcome.

I've seen this 7-8 times in relatively few years of work experience and I interviewed with a company that does a lot of it. They freely admit that they often won't survive a solution analysis or RFP response scoring for many of their larger clients, so they are trying to be sure that you never look at competitors before being pressed to make a decision on them or that if you are required to issue an RFP, they get to help write it so they win.

This vendor is trying to cut you and your evaluation out of the process because that makes it more likely for them to land the business and allows them to charge more as competing offers were never really investigated.

Just tell your manager that you were casually investigating options and ask to be allowed to investigate further to ensure that you get the best deal for the company.

Answer (score 1):

A vendor will use any means at their disposal to give themselves an edge in any sales competition. If they can get your boss on their side, then they don't need to work as hard on a level playing field with all the other candidates.

There are a couple of ways to handle this. Firstly, make sure that your manager is onboard with you continuing your evaluation. If not, then stop right there, apologize to the candidate vendors (except one, maybe :) ), and go back to the day job.

If you continue, you can either shut this vendor out, or contact them with a final warning that YOU are their contact, and any attempts at an end-run will result in them being excluded. The danger there is that if they try another end-run, and succeed, you end up looking a little petty, and you'll have to work with them anyway.

Another approach is to call the manager of the vendor, tell them what happened, and that they're fine to continue with their bid, but with a more ethical salesperson in charge. Same danger as above, of course.

If it was my manager that received the call.. they'd probably have received a few choice words, and be told that if Pete was the contact, Pete is the person they need to talk to. There wouldn't be a dilemma, because it's expected that I'll make several of these investigations each year, only bringing the useful ones to my managers attention.